# Oracle View Conditional Logic

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-view

I have a currency conversion app where when you give it a from currency and a to currency, it returns the exchange rate, e.g.
From USD, To EUR, Rate=2.10

The currencies are held in MY_TABLE.

I want to extend this app to handle cases where a conversion doesn't exist. To do this, I'll reverse the calculation, e.g.

if From USD, To EUR does_not_exist then
return From USD, To EUR, Rate=1 / 2.10.

I will create a view that does this conversion automatically. I am new to view and am asking for a steer on now to do this. Here is my pseudo code. I know it's not right but am I on the right track?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MY_VIEW (FROM_CURR, TO_CURR, RATE) AS
DECLARE
  rates_found number;
BEGIN
      select count(*)
      into   rates_found
      from   MY_TABLE
      where  rownum = 1
      and FROM_CURR = ? and TO_CURR = ?

      if rates_found = 1 then
        select FROM_CURR, 
               TO_CURR, 
               RATE
        from   MY_TABLE
        and FROM_CURR = ? and TO_CURR = ?

      else
        select FROM_CURR, 
               TO_CURR, 
               1 / RATE AS RATE
        from   MY_TABLE
        and FROM_CURR = ? and TO_CURR = ?
END;
```

Comment: you can't have PL/SQL code in a view. You need to create a function

Comment: Perhaps you meant to create a PL/SQL function rather than a SQL view? What is your Oracle version?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Exadata

Comment: What version though? (11.2, 12.1 etc)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want an FX rate lookup function, you might try something like this:

```
create or replace function fx_rate
    ( p_from_curr my_table.from_curr%type
    , p_to_curr   my_table.to_curr%type )
    return my_table.rate%type
    deterministic
as
    pragma udf;
    l_rate my_table.rate%type;
begin
    select min(rate) into l_rate
    from   my_table r
    where  r.from_curr = p_from_curr
    and    r.to_curr = p_to_curr;

    if l_rate is null then
        select 1/rate into l_rate
        from   my_table r
        where  r.from_curr = p_to_curr
        and    r.to_curr = p_from_curr;
    end if;
exception
    when no_data_found then
        return null;
end;
```

`min(rate)` is a bit of a cheat to reduce the amount of exception handling code needed, as it will leave `l_rate` null if no rate is found. I am assuming that only one FX rate is actually held per currency combination.

`pragma udf` reduces context switching (requires Oracle 12.1 or later).

`deterministic` provides caching - however as the function is not strictly deterministic this might be considered a cheat by some.

(To summarise my comments below, this may be a case where we can reasonably ask Oracle to *treat* it as deterministic, even if strictly speaking no lookup function really is, so that if an exchange rate does get updated while a query is running, we explicitly want it to return the old cached result and not the updated version, which is after all what an SQL query would do. Problems could of course arise if Oracle implemented more aggressive caching in a future release, or if the number of distinct values exceeded the implicit cache and so updated values were returned anyway, since `deterministic` makes no guarantees.)

`result_cache` is another option, but I recommend testing performance as there are some overheads associated with the cache validity checking mechanism etc that can impose a minimum response time that could be slower than performing the query. `result_cache` is better suited to functions that take significant resources.

Comment: `deterministic` functions can hamper the result to a extent and it should not be used until we are sure about the result being fix and not going to change irrespective of input.

Comment: I haven't heard of deterministic functions hampering performance if that's what you are saying. As for whether any lookup function is truly deterministic, perhaps not but this may be a case where we can reasonably ask Oracle to treat it as deterministic, so that if an exchange rate does get updated while a query is running we want it to return the old cached result and not the new version, which is after all what an SQL query would do. A problem could of course arise if Oracle implemented more aggressive caching in a future release and the function was not modified.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment by others, you cannot use `PLSQL` code in a `view`. So you need to write a function as below to achieve your requirement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CUR_CON IS OBJECT
(
 col1 VARCHAR2(100),
 col2 VARCHAR2(100),
 col3 number
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE V_CUR_CON IS TABLE OF CUR_CON;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MY_VIEW (FROM_CURR VARCHAR2, TO_CURR VARCHAR2, RATE NUMBER)  
RETURN V_CUR_CON 
AS
  rates_found NUMBER;
  var  V_CUR_CON:=V_CUR_CON();
BEGIN
      select count(*)
      into   rates_found
      from   MY_TABLE
      where  rownum = 1
      and FROM_CURR = ? and TO_CURR = ?

      if rates_found = 1 then
        select CUR_CON (FROM_CURR, 
               TO_CURR, 
               RATE)
        BULK COLLECT INTO var       
        from   MY_TABLE
        and FROM_CURR = ? and TO_CURR = ?

      else
        select CUR_CON (FROM_CURR, 
               TO_CURR, 
               1 / RATE AS RATE)
        BULK COLLECT INTO var
        from   MY_TABLE
        AND FROM_CURR = ? AND TO_CURR = ?

     Return var;   
END;
```

View Definition: Since you wanted to create a view.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_orig_view
as
select * from table(MY_VIEW);
```

Selection:

```
Select * from my_orig_view
```